# Number of online people in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I have a website and i want to find number of online users in my website(All of users logged to their account or not):
And **when they get offline or close page** the number of online users get update:
How can i do that?is there any **library** to do that?

Comment: I think you can handle it using Middleware like this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dfalk/1472104), for usage: `{{ request.online_now }}`, `{{ request.online_now_ids }}`, or `{{ request.online_now.count }}` => to count it all.

Comment: + Don't miss to add into your `MIDDLEWARE = [...]` inside file of `settings.py`

Comment: what should i add to my middleware in setting.py ???

Comment: `MIDDLEWARE = [..., 'path.to.onlinenow.OnlineNowMiddleware']`

Comment: this code at gist i should put at view.py?

Comment: nope, you can create a custom file egg; `onlinenow.py` or `middleware.py`

Comment: i put a code you tell me in setting.py but it raise a error.

Comment: path.to...... i should where path?

Comment: when a put add to middleware it said : Module "mrdoorbeen" does not define a "OnlineNowMiddleware" attribute/class'

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `is_online` BooleanField to your User model and create your own custom `authenticate` [backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) for your User model that after authentication sets the `is_online` to true.

When a user goes to close the web page you can have a event listener to make an Ajax request where you will then set that users `is_online` column to false in DB and logs the user out.

If you don't want to remove the user from sessions you might need additional logic in other places to turn that attribute to true when they come back to the website.

```
// OR
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   // Do something
}, false);
```

You can then find your online users by either doing a `model.objects.filter(is_online=True)` or you can create a custom method on the Model itself that can contain other business logic and or potentially send a email or something.

Comment: I will test it and If it worke I will accept your answer