# How to increase a counter when the user access a webpage and decrease when it leaves using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, analytics

I have a very simple question that may having a tricky answer but I want to know if I want to show a counter on my webpage that increases or decreases when any random user accesss or leave simultaneously then how can I make the function using jQuery?

Comment: Each user can only see their own counter if it is only on the client.. A web counter needs a server part

Comment: Are you able to use: $(document).ready() in the page and then have a function inside of that which increases a number on the page?

Comment: [Perhaps some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+visitor+counter+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: I think there are 2 ways to solve this situation.Join the page and leave it are events which will trigger counter increased or decreased.And the server part afford a api  return the counter value.You can polling the server every centain interval or keep a webservice with server.

Comment: @mplungjan The question is not about a counter counting how many people visited.It like a chatroom,the counter needing decreased when people leave

Comment: @Spikie So call the same code with -1 onbeforeunload

Comment: this page maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978609/number-of-online-people-in-django

Comment: What have you tried so far?